# Is it OK to add [scripting] to questions about Google Apps Script?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking for questions about or related to Google Sheets and/or Google Apps Script.

I found that there aren't specific tags like [google-sheets](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and [google-apps-script](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) that exists in sites like Web Applications and Stack Overflow but there are other tags that could be helpful like [google-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps), [google-drive](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) and [scripting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting)

The tag excerpt for [scripting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) is

> Use this tag to discussing programming which automates the execution of tasks that could alternatively be executed one-by-one by a human operator.

Is it OK to add [scripting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) to questions about Google Apps Script like? :

- [Edit google apps scripts with IntelliJ-IDEA](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25589/14228)
- [How do I sell digital goods in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/70721/14228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question Rubén.

After reading your question, I researched [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).  (It took a little extra time because I block nearly all Google-owned sites!)

From what I read, Google Apps Script looks more similar to a programming language than a scripting language.  It largely resembles JavaScript.

As such, I propose we create a new tag, named 'google-apps-script', and add that tag to all relevant questions.

Comment: Thank you. I assume that we should wait a bit for more answers / votes before proceeding with the new tag creating. By the way, I'm not able to create tags yet.

Comment: You're welcome Rubén.  I agree that it's a good idea to wait a bit for more answers / votes before proceeding.  I'll create the new tag for us if the consensus is to make this the accepted answer.